# Where is IntegrationSpec in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In middle of upgrading to Grails 3.0.1. All good except for integration testing which worked well in 2.4.4.

I've noticed `grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec` is not there in `org.grails:grails-test:3.0.1` any more.

Tried extending `spock.lang.Specification` and running via Gradle `integrationTest` task however **it didn't seems to inject Spring resources**. Also tried `@Integration` getting same error, additionally complained by GGTS:

```
General error during canonicalization: Provider "data" not installed java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "data" not installed at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147) at  
org.grails.io.support.MainClassFinder.searchMainClass(MainClassFinder.groovy:37) at 
org.grails.compiler.injection.test.IntegrationTestMixinTransformation.visit(IntegrationTestMixinTransformation.groovy:82) at 
org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.visitClass(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:150) at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor
...
```

So I'm wondering if `IntegrationSpec` still exists in 3.0. How should I get it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, figured out `@Integration` should be applied and to resolve the compilation error I had to specify `@Integration(applicationClass = Application.class)` because somehow the IDE couldn't find Application class. Of course the test case should extend `Specification`.

`@Autowired` to be used for objects that need to be injected into your test classes. Can't use `@Autowired` in conjunction with `@Shared`, which you can do in 2.x.